# Flask, pass list of dictionaries, getting strings

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I'm learning flask and am trying to pass a list of dictionaries to a redirect. The command `request.args.getlist(list_of_dictionaries` is returning a list of strings. I'm having a hard time understanding how to get them as dictionaries.

Below is my code:

```
a = {'length': '40', 'type': 'phone', 'name': 'Fax', 'label': 'Fax'}
b = {'length': '255', 'type': 'string', 'name': 'Name', 'label': 'Name'}
list_of_dictionaries = [a,b]
listOfObjects = ['Account','Opportunity','Lead']

@app.route('/found', methods=['GET','POST'])
def found():
  keys = request.args.getlist('keys')
  obj = request.args.getlist('obj')
  return render_template("found.html",keys=keys,obj=obj)

@app.route('/finder', methods=['GET','POST'])
def finder():
  if request.method == 'POST'
    return redirect(url_for('clientfound',keys=list_of_dictionaries,obj=listOfObjects))
  else: 
    return render_template('base.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could simply use request.args.get() and then json.loads